# Is it possible to run AKKA on Java 1.5?

Tags: scala, akka

Is it possible to run AKKA on Java 1.5? I'm getting `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file` for `se.scalablesolutions.akka.actor.LocalActorRef`. AKKA version is `0.9.1`
There's noting said about the JVM version limitations at http://doc.akkasource.org/getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem with 0.10. I talked to Viktor Klang about it and i *think* he confirmed that Java 1.5 is not recommended. My advice is:

"Do not even try"

Answer (score 6):

we are leveraging some of the 1.6 features to give Akka some of its awesomeness,
however, if there's enough interest we can definitely consider backporting it to 1.5 as a blessed, for-pay, release bundle.

If you're interested just ping me.

Happy hAkking!

Answer (score 1):

As Scala itself should be backward compatible to Java 1.5, I guess you could pull the Akka sources and try to build it with Java 1.5 yourself. Of course it can happen that Akka relies on a Java class that didn't exist in Java 1.5.

Comment: >> "As Scala itself should be backward compatible to Java 1.5" >> that's why I'm asking - I don't have such problems with Lift that works with 1.5 out-of-the box, but with AKKA it's gotta be trickier... :(

Comment: There was a discussion long ago if Scala should drop the Java 1.4 support (as they did). Since then I never heard anything concerning going away from 1.5 - and frankly, there is not much in Java 1.6 and even 7 which would justify such a step.

Comment: It's likely that Scala 2.9 could require Java 1.5.